# How to get user using forEach loop Mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have an array of IDs looks like

```
get profiles [ '62d80ece61a85d738fa0c297', '62d80fb061a85d738fa0c29c' ]
```

I want to loop this array and every index use it in find() method
My code looks like

```
let total = [];

profile.forEach(async (index) => {
      console.log('index', index);

//OUtput of the console of index 
//index 62d80ece61a85d738fa0c297
//index 62d80fb061a85d738fa0c29c

      let user = await this.userModel.findOne({ _id: index });
      total.push(user);
 console.log('Service', total);
//Output of service is Service []
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Without any information about the schema one solution that I can propose is explicit convert the string to ObjectId